# How to see POSIX permissions on Windows?

Tags: windows-10, permissions, samba, file-sharing

I have a CentOS machine used as a Samba file server with many clients running Windows 10. Sometimes when I have problems, I want to troubleshoot by looking at POSIX permissions. How can I view (and modify) permissions from within Windows?

I know I can do this through ssh, but I'm looking for a Windows option.

Comment: use an FTP client to connect to an FTP service that shows the same files?

Comment: How about cygwin?

Answer (score 1):

You can always view the POSIX ACLs - in terms of user, group, everyone permission with Read/Write/Execute-Bit - by right clicking the folder/file within the network drive --> Properties --> Security. The currently assigned user & group will be shown there and all the permissions mentioned above to it. For a fairly advanced setup with ACLs and domain-joined environment see https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_a_Share_Using_POSIX_ACLs